# replace spaces in part of a text

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I want to replace spaces only in a part of a text.

My input text is as follow,

`---start of text---test1 test2 test3 test4---end is here---`

The output I want is,

```
---start of text--- 
test1
test2
test3
test4
---end is here---
```

I have tried the below command,

```
sed 's/start of text/start~of~text/; s/end is here/end~is~here/; s/text---/text--- /; s/---end/ ---end/' test_file | tr ' ' '\n' | sed 's/~/ /g'
```

this works but for this I have to hard code the start and end of text lines. Is there any way I can avoid this, I tried using gsub in awk but that didn't work.

Comment: Please use CODE TAGS for your samples `{}` button to wrap them up in code tags as your samples are not clear.

Comment: but the code tags are only for the code right, not for the sample input ? (nonetheless edited)

Comment: @ArigatoManga code tags are helpful for samples too to make it visually stand out and avoid sample data getting markdown treatment.. could you add another sample input/output to make your question clearer? `---start of text---` and `---end is here---` is consistent for all your input or there is some other pattern? also, is `perl` okay instead of `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following(considering that your Input_file is same as shown samples).

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="---"} {gsub(" ",ORS,$3);print OFS $2 OFS ORS $3 ORS OFS $(NF-1) OFS}'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="---"} {gsub(" ",ORS,$3);print OFS $2,ORS $3 ORS,$(NF-1) OFS}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
---start of text---
test1
test2
test3
test4
---end is here---
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed, you can add a newline after starting text and before ending text, then loop with a `t` command in between text to replace spaces with newlines:

```
sed -E "s/(---start of text---)(.*)(---end is here---)/\1\n\2\n\3/;:a;s/(\n[^ ]*) (.*\n)/\1\n\2/;ta;" file
```

**Explanations:**

- `s/(---start of text---)(.*)(---end is here---)/\1\n\2\n\3/`: using backreference, adds one newline character after `---start of text---` and one before `---end is here---`
- `:a;s/(\n[^ ]*) (.*\n)/\1\n\2/`: replaces with a new line character the first space found after a `\n` followed by non space characters(`\n[^ ]*`)
- `ta`: a loop to process remaining spaces. `t` is a sed test command that loops to the `a` label when preceding substitution command succeeds

Comment: a great solution !! I was actually trying for a solution like this. can you explain what this part of the pattern will do ? `s/(\n[^ ]*) (.*\n)` I checked printing the \1 \2 individually but didnt understand completely on how it is selecting.